# excels vlookup not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

For some reason my `vlookup` is not working anymore in excel. I use a german version, there the `vlookup` is called `sverweis`.

Excel 2010, 32bit installed on 64bit Windows7.

I tried a simple example, no formating, just data. But I get always the error `#NV`

[image]

[image]

I have no glue whats going on here.

How do I get `vlookup` working again?

Comment: I got it! Its the order of the matrix. It has to be toggled.

Comment: Your lookup column should be the first column

Answer (score 0):

I have never used German version before, but in English version, the separator of parameters is "," other than ";". 
Also, the range (the second parameter) should starts with the column where you really want to compare with. Therefore, if you want to return "3" in the cell B1, you need to swap column D and E, and change the formula to (Eng version)
=VLOOKUP(A1, D1:E3, 2, 0)

Comment: The difference for "," and ";" is down to the system settings language etc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to switch the 2 columns D and E you can use INDEX / MATCH in German INDEX / VERGLEICH as follow:
`INDEX($D$1:$D$3;VERGLEICH(A1;$E$1:$E$3;0))`
IN English:
`=INDEX($D$1:$D$3;MATCH(A1;$E$1:$E$3;0))`
Match will return the row number when there is an exact match the last 0 in the formula
Index will return the corresponding value of the same row